# Find the general solution of the D.E. $ x^2 y'' -2xy'+2y=x\ln(x) $ with $x>1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ x^2 y'' -2xy'+2y=x\ln(x) $$     with $x>1 $.
We can tell that it is a Euler's equation. I started by setting $u=\ln x$,

$$\boxed{u''-2u+2=\dotsb \ ?} $$
Having problems with the $u$ replacement.  What are next steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Plug $y=x^{\lambda}$ into the homogeneous equation to find roots of the characteristic equation, which yields

$$\lambda_1=1, \lambda_2=2$$

Then the homogeneous solution is the linear combination

$$y_{h} = c_1 x+c_2 x^2$$

To find the particular solutions, compute the Wronskian $W(x)$, then divide both sides by $W(x)$. The RHS of the equation now becomes $\frac{\log(x)}{x}=f(x)$. Then the particular solution is of the form

$$y_{p} = v_1(x)\cdot x+v_2(x)\cdot x^2$$

where

$$v_1(x)=-\int\frac{f(x)\cdot x^2}{W(x)}dx, v_2(x)=\int\frac{f(x)\cdot x}{W(x)}dx$$

I leave the calculations to you. The particular solution is $$y_{p} = -\frac{1}{2}x(\ln(x)^2+2\ln(x)+2)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$x^2 y'' -2xy'+2y=x\ln(x)$$
Change the variable $x=e^ t$
$$ y'' -3y'+2y=te^t$$
The DE has constant coefficients.

The characteristic polynomial is:
$$r^2-3r+2=(r-1)(r-2)=0 \implies S_r= \{2,1\}$$
$$\implies y_h=c_1e^t+c_2e^{2t}$$
The particular solution should be of the form:
$$y_p=(At^2+Bt)e^t$$

---

**Another method**

$$x^2 y'' -2xy'+2y=x\ln(x)$$
Divide by $x^2$ and integrate:
$$ y'' -2\left (\dfrac y x \right)'= \dfrac {\ln(x)}x$$
$$ y' -2\left (\dfrac y x \right)=\int \dfrac {\ln(x)}xdx$$
It's a first order DE now.
$$ y' -2\left (\dfrac y x \right)=\frac 12 \ln^2 x +C_1$$

Comment: you mean -2y' instead of -3y' right ? I think that helps. Thanks

Comment: I think it should be $-3y'$ @AlvarezKhan

Comment: Daamn bro...Maybe I should change my course on math. I  understand what you are saying in the 3rd row and so on but I don't understand why its -3 instead of -2...What am I missing ?

Comment: Well you need to change the variable $x=e^t \implies t=\ln x$ you get the DE I posted. @AlvarezKhan